# Use of h:form in Facelets files in /WEB-INF opened by RequestDispatcher#forward() to execute methods of managed beans

Tags: forms, jsf, servlets, managed-bean, commandbutton

I'm using Java EE for an enterprise application on Glassfish.

I have some xhtml files in WEB-INF to prevent direct URL access, that I can access using a servlet. I need to call a method of a managed bean when the user press a button.

The xhtml code I'm using is:

```
<h:form><p:commandButton action="#{managedBean.testFunction()}" value="Test function" type="submit" ajax="false" styleClass="block" /></h:form>
```

The problem is that the input of h:form seems to redirect me to the actual path to my xhtml file, e.g.:

My servlet mapped at:

/ServlerDispatcher/DispatcherServlet

using:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/HiddenFiles/fileA.xhtml").forward(request, response);
```

displays the xhtml file in the WEB-INF folder, that contains the form I mentioned above. Submitting the form, by pressing the button redirects me to this URL:

```
/ServlerDispatcher/WEB-INF/HiddenFiles/fileA.xhtml``
```

that cannot be displayed since it's in the WEB-INF folder to prevent direct URL access.

As I said what I really need is execute a managed bean method when the user press a button. How can I do that?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: Is this your colleague? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28041538/execute-commandbutton-beanfunction-in-web-inf-page-xhtml-coming-from-forward

Comment: Yes, he is. We are doing this project in collaboration.

Comment: Better work together and don't ask duplicate questions.

Comment: Well I sent him the link to this post, I don't know why he asked his question. I also said him, before his question, that I solved the exception he mentioned  (that was caused by a portion of code that he didn't display in his code) and explained him the reason. To recap, I'm sorry but really I agree with you, this doesn't make much sense to me either