# Execute commandButton-beanFunction in WEB-INF/page.xhtml coming from forward

Tags: jsf, servlets, forward, commandbutton, web-inf

I'm using Java EE for an enterprise application on Glassfish 4.1, I've the following components:

a Java Servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    this.setUser(um.getLoggedUser());

    final String indexPath =  "/Index.xhtml";
    final String creatorPath =  "/WEB-INF/HiddenPages/EventPageCreator.xhtml";

    if(creator())
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/HiddenPages/Creator.xhtml").forward(request, response);
    else
        response.sendRedirect("/Index.xhtml");
}
```

The creator page that is under WEB-INF,is the page in which arises the problem:
It's related to a ManagedBean method.

```
<h:form><p:menubar>
    <p:menuitem action="#{bean.logout()}" value="Logout" ajax="false">
</p:menuitem></p:menubar></h:form>
```

The bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean(){
    public void logout(){
        System.out.println("logout");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the page Creator.xhtlm is rightly loaded with all the css and also the properties given by that bean. The problem is that once I click on the logout menuitem it doesn't call the related function and an 500 Internal Error occurs, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed.

Comment: Why this awkward approach? Answer would be to stop using `RequestDispatcher#forward()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the attention. The problem is that by using a sendRedirect for going to pages under WEB-INF I fall in a 404. This is the reason for that solution. Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't put them in `/WEB-INF`. That's only for MVC frameworks using JSP files which can't be mapped on the same extension as the view file itself. `FacesServlet` can however easily be mapped on `*.xhtml`. And, to perform user role based access restriction, use a filter which simply calls `chain.doFilter()`, not a servlet.

Comment: I've already tried with this solution but there is a problem with the loading of the primefaces theme. Even if it's declared in the pom file. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: That was already told to your colleague.